# Como detener un script php sin afectar al html

Tags: php, html

Estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un archivo index.php donde tengo también código html, resulta ser que al hacer una validación if y querer detener el script con exit(), no se muestra el código html.

Adjunto ejemplo

```
<php
If(condicion == true){
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']) && $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] > time()) {
    // Finaliza el script
    // Solo se muestra mensaje de error
   exit() ;
}

// Inicializar variable de error
$error = '';
// ¿Debe haber un captcha? Por defecto no, hasta verificar cantidad de intentos
$captcha = false;

$usuario = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'usuario'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$clave = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'clave'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}else{
//otras validaciones 
} 
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="usuario">
    <input type="text" name="clave">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
    
</form>
```

Comment: Porque usar exit? Si esta dentro de una condicion. Sobre lo que no se muestra, es por eso mismo, porque estas usando exit

Comment: Porque luego de esa condición hay otras condiciones dentro, pero no son anidadas, son independientes, entonces hay una de ellas que solo si se cumple esa se debe detener el script, entonces si no pongo el exit, se ejecuta todo el resto de código que viene abajo

Comment: Creo que deberias poner eso en tu pregunta (Las partes importantes). Ya que tu problema es eso, creo que se solucionaria ordenando, porque usar exit no es conveniente. Por otra parte si solamente quieres que se ejecute el script cuando cumple esa condicion, porque no lo anidas?

Comment: Edite la pregunta, ahí puse la condición que si se cumple se debe detener el script, si no se cumple esa condición, debe seguir el script de forma normal

Comment: Por lo que me muestras, deberias agrupar el codigo en la condicion poniendo un `!` adelante, algo asi: `if ( !(isset($_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']) && $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] > time()) ){ $error = ''; .... }`. Cosa que "si no se cumple" ejecutara el codigo